# PyQt5 opening and closing windows

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have two UI windows created with QT Designer. I have two separate python scripts for each UI. What I'm trying to do is the first script opens a window, creates a thread that looks for a certain condition, then when found, opens the second UI. Then the second UI creates a thread, and when done, opens the first UI.

This seems to work fine, here's the partial code that is fired when the signal is called:

```
def run_fuel(self):
    self.st_window = L79Fuel.FuelWindow(self)
    self.thread.exit()
    self.st_window.show()
    self.destroy()
```

So that appears to work fine. I am still unsure of the proper way to kill the thread, the docs seem to state exit() or quit(). But...the new window from the other script (L79Fuel.py) is shown and the old window destroyed.

Then the new window does some things, and again when a signal is called, it triggers an similar function that I'd like to close that window, and reopen the first window.

```
def start_first(self):
    self.r_window = L79Tools.FirstWindow(self)
    self.thread.exit()
    self.r_window.show()
    self.destroy()
```

And this just exits with a code 0. I stepped through it with a debugger, and what seems to be happening is it runs through `start_first`, does everything in the function, and then goes back to the first window's `sys.exit(app.exec_())`, does that line, and then loops back to the `start_first` function (the second window) and executes that code again, in a loop, over and over.

I'm stumped. I've read as much as I could find, but nothing seems to address this. I'm guessing there's something I'm doing wrong with the threading (both windows have a thread going) and I'm not killing the threads correctly, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer?  `self.hide()`

I was doing `self.destroy` on the windows to get rid of them, but what I didn't realize was that also was causing the program to start the process to exit completely. So it seems the answer is to kill the thread, and then simply `.hide()` the window. Now, each window opens and closes, multiple times if needed, while starting and stopping threads. New code (each function is essentially the same) below:

```
def run_race(self):
    self.thread.stop()
    self.thread.wait()
    self.thread = None
    self.r_window = L79Race.RaceWindow(self)
    self.r_window.show()
    self.hide()
```

While the threading wasn't the problem, I thought it was better to completely kill the thread before creating the next window. The `self.thread.stop()` is shown below. I realize `.terminate()` is not recommended, but I'm not really writing or trying to save anything in the thread, so I'm not worried about when it closes, only that it does.

```
def stop(self):
    self.terminate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the main thread can create GUI elements.  You won't be able to create a second window in another thread.  It's hard to see exactly how your program is set up based on the two callback slots in your question.

Generally, you kill threads with `quit`

```
self.thread.quit()
```

If you want, you can wait until it full quits and then delete the reference

```
self.thread.wait()
self.thread = Nonee
```

Comment: Most likely, your creating them via functions that aren't in other threads, even though they're being triggered from other threads

Comment: I found the answer. It's quite simple actually. I'll post it and mark it.